# deliver_now Method of the Gem mail produces wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm a bit stuck on upgrading the Ruby version of my Rails project. The project is running on Rails 6.1.7 and I have upgraded the Ruby version to 3.2.2. However, my tests show that there is a problem with the `deliver_now` method of the Gem `mail` (version 2.8.1).

The following call produces the following error:

```
Call: TestMailer.test_mail(one: foo, two: bar).deliver_now
Error: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: one, two) (ArgumentError)
```

The corresponding method definition looks like this:

```rb
def test_mail(one:, two:)
    attach_files([one.last.pdf_path.to_s]) if two

    send_mail(one: one)
end
```

I have a very strong suspicion that the problem is the Gem mail in version 2.8.1. If I fix the version in the Gemfile to `gem 'mail', '2.7.1'` and raise the Ruby version "only" to 3.0.4, the whole thing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not `mail` gem. Rails 6.1.7 is not compatible with ruby 3.2 - the keyword changes introduced in ruby 3.1 requires rails 7.0.1 (not even 7.0.0) version to work properly. This unfortunately means you need to upgrade Rails first.